# Terminate Shell command

Tags: shell, execution, termination, interruption

I've been executing such a large .SH file via Cygwin. I just want terminate the execution of .SH while executing (like ctrl+x in command prompt)..

What key combination needs to be given for terminating .SH file execution while executing?

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

If you're using `Cygwin` on your local station, you could also just try to close its window.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>(*this terminate the current process, also it may be that the given software handles it and and you dont need CTRL+C*). And if this fails, kill the process .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for either cntrl-c or cntrl-z.
With C you Cancel the job and with Z you let send it to the back. Where you can fd back to it or kill it.